# Using toastr in AngularJS for confirmation dialog

Tags: angularjs, toastr

I am somewhat of a noob to Angular.
Inside one of my controllers, I am setting some global options on toastr and invoking a toastr
method exposed via a factory (tndNotifier). This seems to work fine, but what I do not like
is the fact that when I click anything other than the "Continue" button or "x" within the toastr
div, I end up invoking the onclick event. I am trying to ignore that outright so that a user
does not end up inadvertantly invoking the onclick event. Seems like this might not be possible, but I could be wrong. Also, the button click does not dismiss the toastr instance.

```
  promptForDeleteServiceLog: function(serviceLog) {
      // I am sure I can hide toastr behind some other abstraction to avoid a direct reference
      toastr.options = {
        tapToDismiss: false,
        closeButton: true,
        onclick: function(object) {
          $scope.tndServiceLogList.deleteServiceLog(serviceLog);
        }
      };
      // Embedding markup here makes me feel dirty
      tndNotifier.warn('You are about to delete ' + serviceLog.description + '. Click \'Continue\' to delete or \'x\' to cancel.' +
          ' <br><br><button class="btn btn-warning">Continue</button>');
    }
```

The factory is defined as such:

```
angular.module('app').value('tndToastr', toastr);

angular.module('app').factory('tndNotifier', function(tndToastr) {
  return {
    notify: function(msg) {
      tndToastr.success(msg);
      console.log(msg);
    },
    warn: function(msg) {
      tndToastr.warning(msg);
      console.log(msg);
    },
    error: function(msg) {
      tndToastr.error(msg);
      console.log(msg);
    }
  }
});
```

The reason I am using toastr is because it offers me a common notification mechanism. Should I be using toastr in this manner (for confirmation dialogs) or should I instead write a custom directive to popup a div without actually using toastr at all? What is the preferred approach for my use case?

I have an idea that maybe I should be using jQuery within a directive to try to achieve a similar look and feel (and behavior) to toastr, but I do not know the best approach.

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raigsingh/yq7jhfmr/) illustrates what I described above.

Comment: toastr isn't meant to be used for input. It is a notification library. You should be using something like angular ui bootstraps modal directive.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. I started to see the error in my ways when I was trying to force the solution via toastr with embedded markup. I haven't used the angular ui bootstrap modal just yet so I will give that a try.

Comment: Well wait now, there is a solution to your problem though ;-)

Answer (score 1):

### Based on your fiddle:

The `toastr` global that you are setting your configuration object is not the same as your `tndToastr` `value` provider, so therefore calling events on tndToaster wont respect the configuration you passed it.:

```
// Wrong Way. 
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, tndNotifier) {
  $scope.tndServiceLogList = {
    promptForDeleteServiceLog: function (serviceLog) {
      toastr.options = { //This is not the same toastr variable as your injectable tndToastr that you defined, so therefore calling events on tndToaster wont resepct this config.
        tapToDismiss: false,
        closeButton: true
      };
      tndNotifier.warn('You are about to delete  FOO. Click \'Continue\' to delete or \'x\' to cancel.' +
        ' <br><br><button class="btn btn-warning">Continue</button>');
    }  };
});
```

### Inject `tndToaster` and configure it:

If you instead inject your value as seen below and then call the configuration on it, you see the desired behavior you are looking for.

```
// Way that does work in updated fiddle
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, tndNotifier, tndToastr) {
  $scope.tndServiceLogList = {
    promptForDeleteServiceLog: function (serviceLog) {
      tndToastr.options = {
        tapToDismiss: false,
        closeButton: true
      };
      tndNotifier.warn('You are about to delete  FOO. Click \'Continue\' to delete or \'x\' to cancel.' +
        ' <br><br><button class="btn btn-warning">Continue</button>');
    }  };
});
```

Here is the updated <kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yq7jhfmr/27/)</kbd> with the updated controller.

#### Sidenote: Should I be using toast notifications as a modal?

[Seth Flowers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444610/seth-flowers) makes a good point that you probably shouldn't be using a notification library to generate what looks to be modals in UI/UX. However, if it walks like a duck, talks like a duck, then it is a duck. If it has all the functionality you need without having to have the crap out of it, then I'm sure it might be safe to use. I would recommend looking at the ui-modal components that are out there or other options on http://ngmodules.org/.

Comment: Thank you for the example and explanation. However, I noticed the same behavior with and without the added reference to the tndToastr provider (toastr does not dismiss automatically). It all does seem a little clunky as I should expect. So I will most likely move to using angular UI bootstrap modal as I realized that I am using angular ui-bootstrap for datepickers in my app already.

Comment: If you could confirm that the example provided does not work, I can go ahead and accept your answer. I just do not want someone else to assume that toastr is in any way a working solution to a modal confirmation dialog problem.

Comment: Didn't you say that you didn't want the toast to dismiss *unless* you clicked on the cancel button or X?

Comment: No, I stated that the button click does not dismiss the toastr. I can see how you might think that I meant to keep it visible, but my attempt to use 'tapToDismiss: false' was to force it to dismiss automatically.

Comment: I understand now, then I would say that you are better using ui-bootstrap-modal then.